# Emberjs transitionToRoute, passing model results in undefined

Tags: ember.js

Let me preface and say I am new to ember, trying to learn the ropes.

After a successful ajax request I am trying to `transitionToRoute('qualified',data);` Data is an array of objects, currently `[object1,object2,object3,object4]` My route is currently set up as following:

`this.resource('qualified', {path: '/:data'});`

This results in /#/qualified/undefined

My QualifiedController has the data I need to populate the page, and I need all for indexes of the array for the page. How do I instantiate data as my Model for qualified and remedy the undefined URL issue?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You must pass an object instead of the array inside your route:

```
this.transitionTo('qualified', data[0]);
```

Comment: thanks for the input. So what do I do with my router to access this data.